# How to count in pivot table in Laravel 5

Tags: model-view-controller, model, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I would like to know how I can count how often an ingredient occurs in all recipes.

Because I'm using `withPivot` it's harder to achieve (I think).

**Model Ingredient:**

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{
    public function receipt()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Receipt','receipt_ingredients','ingredient_id','receipt_id')->withPivot('amount');
    }
}
```

**Model Receipt**

```
class Receipt extends Model
{
    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Ingredient','receipt_ingredients','receipt_id','ingredient_id')->withPivot('amount');
    }
}
```

**Model ReceiptIngredient** (my pivot table)

```
class ReceiptIngredient extends Model
{
    public $table = 'receipt_ingredients';

    public function receipt()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Receipt');
    }

    public function ingredient()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Ingredient');
    }
}
```

In the end, I would like to have a list of each ingredient with the number of occurences in recipes.

**Screenshot of table structure for "receipt_ingredients"**

[receipt_ingredients table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEp7B.jpg)

Comment: I don't  think you need to create a model for the pivot, also your pivot table should be named `ingredient_receipt` if we folllow the laravel convention

Comment: Oh, you're right! I should rename it. Thank you! 
Maybe it's possible to use this Pivot-Model to count that stuff - I have to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way to do it but you can just use DB facade to access your pivot table.

```
$ingredientCount = DB::table('ingredient_receipt')
          ->groupBy('ingredient_id')
          ->where('ingredient_id', $ingredient_id)
          ->count();
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, thank you. 
My Pivot-Model was also good and can accomplish the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was nice.

Now follows the next step:
The method above counts an occurence by ingredient_id.

But - how can I accomplish the following:

- Fetch all ingredients which occur in recipes
- Count each ingredient
- **Sort** ingredients DESC.
- Return them as array/model